# How to tell whether OS Level APIs support multithread?

Tags: python, multithreading, api, operating-system

This question might be a bit blurry, so sorry in advance.

Recently, I need to use some Clipboard APIs on all major platforms (Linux, MacOS, Windows). And I want to use the API in a multithreaded environment, so I'd like to know whether the API supports it or not.

I found these kinds of information is very difficult to find in the documentation ( I found none so far..). And I start to wonder why the documents don't mention it? Is there a reason? Should I make the assumption that APIs are single-threaded unless explicit mentions? If so, why is that, security concerns?

I found the only way to tell is to write some dummy code, and check on each platform.

Here's a dummy code snippet for gtk on Linux. I run the GUI in the main thread, and use the clipboard API in a different thread.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject

import threading
import logging
import os

GObject.threads_init()

class ClipboardWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Clipboard Example")

        table = Gtk.Table(3, 2)

        self.clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name("process-stop", Gtk.IconSize.MENU)

        button_copy_text = Gtk.Button("Copy Text")
        button_paste_text = Gtk.Button("Paste Text")
        button_copy_image = Gtk.Button("Copy Image")
        button_paste_image = Gtk.Button("Paste Image")

        table.attach(self.entry, 0, 1, 0, 1)
        table.attach(self.image, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        table.attach(button_copy_text, 1, 2, 0, 1)
        table.attach(button_paste_text, 2, 3, 0, 1)
        table.attach(button_copy_image, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        table.attach(button_paste_image, 2, 3, 1, 2)

        button_copy_text.connect("clicked", self.copy_text)
        button_paste_text.connect("clicked", self.paste_text)
        button_copy_image.connect("clicked", self.copy_image)
        button_paste_image.connect("clicked", self.paste_image)

        self.add(table)

    def copy_text(self, widget): # Runs in a different thread 
        print("Copy Text Start at " + str(threading.get_ident()));
        x = threading.Thread(target=self._copy_text, args=(widget,))
        x.start()
        x.join()

    def _copy_text(self, widget):
        self.clipboard.set_text(self.entry.get_text(), -1)
        print("Copy Text DONE at " + str(threading.get_ident()));
        
    def paste_text(self, widget):
        print("Paste Text Start at " + str(threading.get_ident()));
        x = threading.Thread(target=self._paste_text, args=(widget,))
        x.start()
        x.join()

    def _paste_text(self, widget): # Runs in a different thread
        text = self.clipboard.wait_for_text()
        if text is not None:
            self.entry.set_text(text)
        else:
            print("No text on the clipboard.")
        print("Paste Text DONE at " + str(threading.get_ident()));

    def copy_image(self, widget):
        if self.image.get_storage_type() == Gtk.ImageType.PIXBUF:
            self.clipboard.set_image(self.image.get_pixbuf())
        else:
            print("No image has been pasted yet.")

    def paste_image(self, widget):
        image = self.clipboard.wait_for_image()
        if image is not None:
            self.image.set_from_pixbuf(image)
print("Main at " + str(threading.get_ident()));
win = ClipboardWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: If you posted your dummy code, we could see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, please give more details.  AFAIK there is only one  clipboard per desktop and GUI interfaces are run by one thread only.  I don't understand your question.  The clipboard is available to whichever thread is handling a window that has focus.  In general, the API calls to an OS that supports multiple threads is thread-safe unless specified otherwise..

Comment: Sorry about that, I added my dummy code.

Comment: GTK functions are usually only callable from the main thread.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's is also what I am told, but my code seems to work which would run `wait_for_text` and `set_text` in a non-main thread?